# Notify me when a question that I follow gets reopened

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, follow-posts

I recently followed a closed question and I was waiting to get notified when it was reopened but got nothing.

Is this by design, or a bug?

It's said ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/386331)) that:

> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices

What is the scope of notices? Isn't reopening included?

If it's not included it would be good to have such notification.

Comment: the text doesn't mention "reopen". It mentions "new answers, comments, edits, and notices. But reopening would be a nice addition.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre but what does *notices* mean?

Comment: it's a banner that moderators can add to the post.

Comment: Aren't close and lock states also considered "notices" now?

Comment: @CodyGray considering this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/386331 yes it's. So logically I should get a notification on notice removal since this is what happen on reopen.

Comment: @CodyGray I assume its just actual [notices](https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed) as opposed to anything with a banner

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for the request! We've implemented this, and it's now live. Now, when a user is following a question, when that question is reopened, they'll get a notification indicating that.

Comment: That's nice! Are you notified if gets closed as well? Or if it receives reopen votes? Both things [could be useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402441/1426539) as well.

Comment: We currently don't notify if a question is closed (or if it receives reopen votes), and it's not included in this update, but it's something that we're considering.

Comment: @yivi post authors and followers [are now notified when questions are closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/question-closed-notifications-experiment-results-and-graduation).

Comment: Awesome @Yaakov!