# Enable follow notifications for answers when a rollback happens

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, rollbacks, follow-posts

Currently, there will be no notification if someone rolls back edit on an answer even if you are following the post. However, this kind of feature would be very useful mostly when encountering vandalism or improving low-quality answers.

Can we have the follow functionality for rollbacks too, please?

Comment: also this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397829/8620333 not yet considered

Comment: Added this to the spreadsheet detailing the different follow notifications https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zU-o6cr9DeLKB3na9aEld13Ixf30f4qpGWPidILtmPs/view

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We've implemented this feature. When a question or answer you are following is rolled back to a previous edit, you'll now receive a notification for that as well. Thanks for the request! And as an aside, testing for this new notification helped us spot an issue with our testing infrastructure, so thanks for the bonus benefit, too.

Comment: What about on rollbacks on deleted posts? Will they also trigger a notification?