# We need to improve the chances of reopening closed questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, notifications, vote-to-reopen

### The situation

It’s a well-known fact that closed questions tend to *stay* closed. This makes sense: most questions are closed for a good reason.

But sometimes the asker puts in the work, edits the question, fixes the issues, and wants it reopened. And *sometimes* the question actually gets reopened!

But let’s be honest: (except for duplicates) **reopening happens rarely**, because the question flies under the radar. Yes, editing bumps it to the home page. But it has that big ugly mark next to it: “[closed]”. And thus most people will (with good reason) ignore it entirely (personally I almost never click on “[closed]” questions). And the question stays closed.

Furthermore, the [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) is completely ineffective in practice; in my experience, it hasn’t led to a *single* question being reopened (see below). Part of the reason may be that questions are only put into this queue *once*, even when they get edited repeatedly (and the first edit is often a minor cosmetic change by somebody other than the author, and wouldn’t warrant reopening).

I’ve started following questions that I personally voted to close, but where I see potential for the OP to improve it to justify reopening. And this does happen regularly, and I get notified, and I vote to reopen. And then … **nothing.** *Not a single* such questions has been reopened, despite all issues in the comments being addressed (I’m excluding duplicates here: questions incorrectly closed as duplicates get reopened fairly frequently).

The other close-voters don’t turn up. I don’t blame them, there’s thankfully no compulsion to subscribe to/follow questions you voted to close. But since nobody else bothers looking at the question, it doesn’t get the second chance it deserves, *and this is immensely frustrating*, and breaks the very explicit promise to newcomers that “your question was closed for reason X. Amend the question to get it reopened.”

### The proposal

There needs to be some kind of mechanism to prevent this. Flagging for moderator attention is (IMHO) *not* the right mechanism, since it puts the onus on the moderators. I’d love a way to incentivise others to check out edited questions to appraise their reopen-worthiness. Neither bumping to the homepage nor the review queue currently do this.

**Here’s what I’m proposing:** Ideally, the people who closed the question should be reminded to take a look after the question was edited by the original author, whether they are following the question or not. I think this might be an unpopular proposal but I don’t believe it’s too much to ask of close-voters. At the very least this should be *trialled* to see whether it actually leads to a lot of notification spam.

(I currently @-mention the other close-voters in comments but this requires goodwill on the part of the other close-voters (and gives them disproportionate power), as well as serendipity: nobody is always online and sees the flag in a reasonable time frame.)

---

(There are [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266709/1968) [discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366990/1968) about this topic but (a) they are *ancient* (the most recent one is more than *2.5 years old*), (b) they precede other recent change such as the “follow” function; they thus happened in a completely different context, (c) they aren’t a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and (d) there’s no resolution, not even an attempt at one. **This still needs fixing.**)

Comment: And you can also go post a [tag:reopen-pls] request in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), but make sure to read the FAQ.

Comment: Do you have some hard statistics on what percentage of questions that go into the reopen queue age out (and therefore are not reopened) vs the ones that get acted upon (either reopened or voted to stay closed).

Comment: Maybe we should introduce [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen)? Would be very quick implementation of the FR... I'm not really sure what this FR actually proposes so...

Comment: I will speculate that if you look at the timeline for those posts, they went into the reopen queue and users just voted to keep them closed :(

Comment: @10Rep If a user votes to reopen, which they have said they did, it gets pushed into the reopen queue, no? :) Also, you can't assume that everyone knows that the first edit to a closed Question pushes it into the queue.

Comment: @Scratte But it does, doesn't it? Any edit made by the OP after their question was closed will be pushed into the queue, no? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @10Rep No, the first edit by _any_ user (that did not close the question), will push it into the queue, it doesn't matter if it's OP or not. Even half-assed edits from the suggested edit queue will push the question into the reopen queue if approved. Either way, it will only be pushed into the queue via editing a single time. Which is why I would like to see only OPs edits push their questions into the reopen queue, saves them from having crap edits take their one chance at reopening away from them.

Comment: @Nick Really? That sucks a lot, And I feel the question should adress that.

Comment: @10Rep Why should this post address that? The topic of this post is basically: What to do when a closed edited Question doesn't get reopened? It has to be focused, so it can't address everything, including: How does it enter the queue? But alas, it was closed anyway :( ..ironically, since we know closed Question are almost impossible to reopen.

Comment: @10Rep Just empirically, it’s obvious that bumping it to the reopen queue is completely ineffectual. I thought my question addressed that (though not in so many words). I’ve added a paragraph now.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The hard statistics from all the ones I am involved in is that 0% (**zero per cent**) get reopened.

Comment: @Scratte That’s indeed an interesting speculation but, from my experience, that’s *not* what’s happening.

Comment: It’s also incredibly disappointing to have all this comment discussion, yet the question is closed as an alleged “duplicate” of other, ancient discussions that it’s patently not a duplicate of. *Related*, yes. But not a duplicate.

Comment: You might be interested on the data presented on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286309/1426539).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Fair enough. But you can check just to be sure, no? Allow for 14 days to pass to get the result of the reopen queue on the timeline. About the closure of this post. I'm very disappointed with it too. It feels like the issue is just getting swept under the rug.

Comment: @Scratte Yes, I think it’s a valid point, and I did check that for a handful of questions.

Comment: @yivi I simply don’t agree with that, not least because this question (but not the others) is very intentionally tagged [meta-tag:feature-request]. The other questions will **never** elicit a reaction from Stack Overflow — they have been addressed in the past, and the response has been inadequate. This needs to be addressed from scratch.

Comment: @yivi I don’t propose a *concrete* feature but the text above *does* make a suggestion.

Comment: Shog9's Answer to [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/12695027) has some good suggestions of how to create feature-requests, in case you haven't read it yet.

Comment: @yivi I hear you. If I had a magical solution I would have offered it. I don’t, which is why the feature request is paired with a discussion. I fundamentally don’t think that makes it a worthless or invalid feature request. I *am* requesting a feature, and finding and developing this feature requires discussion.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375365/how-do-i-present-a-proposal-for-change-or-write-a-feature-request-for-stack-over) is also a good read if one wants to propose a change.

Comment: @yivi By the way, thanks for the link to the data. Unfortunately I think the data is even less useful than my (admittedly) extremely limited data from own experience, which [I’ve explained in a reply to deceze](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402432/we-really-need-to-improve-the-chances-of-reopening-closed-questions#comment804882_402432) (besides which the linked data is obviously ancient and no longer even captures the current close reasons accurately).

Comment: @yivi Actually you have a point. I’ve added a concrete feature request now.

Comment: @Trilarion Our edits crossed. I’ve added a concrete feature request now.

Comment: What is so bad about a 2.5 year old content to mark it as ancient? I frequently read 10 year old posts and often they feel spot on.

Comment: A similar sentiment was my motivation for [(re-)proposing the follow feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393314/476) as well. Dispersing the close/reopen power among all users of the site makes little sense. It'd be a lot more helpful to keep the original close-voters in the loop instead of shunting that job off to entirely unrelated randos in the reopen queue.

Comment: @Trilarion I can’t say I feel the same: Stack Overflow 10 years ago was a completely different place in almost every regard. The pace of change at Stack Overflow may feel glacial from the perspective of an instant but there *is* change. In this concrete case, the site handled close votes differently 2.5 years ago, question asking was different 2.5 years ago, and the “follow” function didn’t exist.

Comment: @deceze While I can understand the sentiment, I believe there are way too many more questions that are closed, get edited, and remain unfit for the site (or remain dupes) than the other way around. Getting automated notifications/following on every close-vote would be seriously noisy and not productive. The "follow" feature at least makes the process opt-in, which I think is as it should be.

Comment: @yivi Agreed. But the follow feature has proven quite positive, I feel. (Speaking entirely anecdotally, unfortunately.) I'm not saying that all close votes should lead to a mandatory follow, but it's absolutely worth it to rethink this workflow.

Comment: I for one would be interested to try getting a notification _after first reopen vote_ (from some other user) on a question where I am one of close voters

Comment: @gnat That’s an excellent suggestion, could you make it an answer?

Comment: [there you go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402437/839601)

Comment: As a side-note, you cannot ping the close voters, unless they cast a binding close vote (gold badge dupe hammer or mod), you'd have to ping them on posts they have interacted with otherwise to be able to do that.

Comment: I made several proposals for fixing the way closed questions go into the reopen queue [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395911/5211833).

Comment: I wonder why this is a problem at all. Isn't there a reopen review queue? If it isn't clogged, closed questions should get quite a number of eyes looking at them. On the other hand, most closed questions do not improve even with edits, is my experience. Maybe the close vote review queue should be blocked if the reopen review queue is full for example has more than a couple of hundred entries.

Comment: This is not my experience.  I see plenty of closed questions get re-opened, even ones that should not be re-opened.

Comment: By default, I don't want a notification.  I already routinely use the "Active" tab to see which questions that I am interested in have been updated.  If this feature were to be implemented, it should disabled by default, and users should opt-in.

Comment: @toolic I've seen worse than that: locked.

Comment: @Trilarion I believe my question already addresses the inadequacy of the reopen queue.

Comment: You just describe that you vote to reopen and the question remains closed. That can have two possible causes, either nobody reviewed it or the reviewers in the queue thought it should remain closed. What is the case in your examples? If it's the case that the other reviewers think that it should be closed, do you simply disagree with them? It's not clear to me what exactly the inadequacies of the reopen queue are in your opinion other that it doesn't reopen.

Comment: @Trilarion You’ve missed this part: “Part of the reason may be that questions are only put into this queue once, even when they get edited repeatedly”. You’ve also missed that the reopen rate I’ve observed is 0%. Of course maybe I’m wrong 100% of the time, but you have to admit that this is becoming less likely than the alternative explanation, that the queue is ineffective.

Comment: At least someone must be wrong, either you or the other users who seem to negatively review the question in the queue. Would the original close voters really decide differently from the other reviewers in the reopen queue? Maybe the timing or frequency of submission to the review queue is a bad choice because the question is typically not yet in shape. In that case it would make more sense that a reopen vote would just trigger an additional round of review. I thought we are doing that already. Maybe I only imagine it but I thought that in timelines I saw multiple reopen review rounds.

Comment: @Trilarion Nobody needs to be “wrong” if we posit that no meaningful effort is spent re-assessing closed questions fairly. I don’t *know* whether that’s the true but I strongly suspect that this is the very often the case, and common sense makes this at least plausible, since intentional effort is required to overturn the “status quo” of leaving closed questions closed.

Comment: Just an idea, but one could found a SORVR (analogously to the SOCVR), i.e. a couple of dedicated users to efficiently use their reopen votes to quickly reopen questions that deserve it. That would probably have an impact. You would just post the question that you voted to reopen in some chat room and others could look at them. It seems to be the same workaround to the same problem that also is reason for the existence of the SOCVR.

Comment: @Trilarion SOCVR fields reopen requests as well. The problem is that questions needing reopening it's simply a much less frequent occurrence. Having two active rooms with such different and potentially competing viewpoints could be "fun", for certain values of "fun"

Comment: @yivi How is it a problem that one type of event happens more rarely than another. Specialists in closing should also be specialists in reopening.  Maybe the SOCVR has some conventions what to do in controversial cases? How are they proceeding if some say yes, please close and others say no, don't do it? It could work, the goal is the same in a way: close things that need to be closed and open things that need to be opened.

Comment: @Trilarion, you are right, it’s not a problem. I misspoke. I meant that the reason it happens much less often is simply because it’s much less frequent occurrence (and arguably a less serious problem), nothing more.

Comment: Short answer: no we don't. Long: see the percentage of edited after closure questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286309). It makes no sense to waste all our energy as curators on all these when askers are not even willing to put a fraction of that into their own questions. The rising number of closed questions that are not reopened is merely a reflection of the fact that the number of users of the website has only increased over time. More users -> more bad content -> saturation -> higher bad/good content ratio.

Comment: @Marco I simply don’t understand how you reach that conclusion. First off, those numbers are seriously outdated. See TheMaster’s answer below for up to date numbers. And secondly, 17% closed questions edited isn’t little — given that a third of *all* questions gets closed, that’s a substantial overall number of questions that may deserve a second chance (not all of them do; not even the majority; but even the remainder of that is still absolutely non-negligible).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't necessarily see a problem with that. I would choose close + delete + re-ask in a decent form every day of the week over close + struggle to reopen.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli As would I, because we both know that the system is heavily stacked against reopening. But new users don’t know that. Your advice is violating all rules of good UX.

Comment: I don't really see any solution that would not increase work of site curators other than making the users aware of the fact that the system works this way, and educating them, which I think we already do. I believe that the current situation will not change unless curators put more work in. We have simply reached a natural equilibrium, and we just need to acknowledge the fact that X% of people just can't be bothered to read and understand the site rules, which can't really get much clearer than what they are now.

Comment: On top of that, as I already stated, as the total number of questions and users increases, the percentage of closed questions increases too. This is simply because more existing Q/A leads to more duplicates, and even maintaining the same ratio of other close reasons, the overall closure ratio increases. "Reopening happens rarely" - this is definitely true, but I don't think it happens more rarely than it should.

Comment: *"Ideally, the the people who closed the question should be reminded to take a look"* - if *this* is not bad UX I don't know what is. It would just automatically make me stop voting to close (unless it's opt-out). Nonetheless, it's still a solution that creates more work for site curators, which again, supports the point I'm trying to make: cannot solve this unless curators work more.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli “we just need to acknowledge the fact that X% of people just can't be bothered …” — My question acknowledges that *at the very beginning*. Can *you*, in turn, please acknowledge *that*? We are talking about those users that *are* bothered, and who are willing to put in the necessary work. Let’s please stop getting side-tracked discussing other users. The question isn’t about them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph your suggestion is a valid one, in fact probably the only possible one, that's a +1 for me, even though I don't find it much viable.

Comment: Without additional restrictions, "*[close voters get notifications ...] whether they are following the question or not.*" is simply a non-starter. I do not want or need ~46,000 notifications, thank you. The *first* change the company should make is to stop putting questions in the reopen queue when they're edited by someone other than OP. Then we can see how things start to look. Reopening on Stack Overflow is already 40% easier than yesteryear, ever since the threshold was changed to 3 votes. Considering many times askers reopen vote themselves, you often only need *two* votes to reopen a Q.

Comment: Also FWIW I felt the question score floor experiment was quite successful (apparently I'm alone in that). If questions stopped showing drops at -2 or -3, I think they'd get a lot fewer pile-on downvotes. Combine that re-implemented feature with a change to questions dropping off the homepage at -2 instead of -4 and I think questions stand a much better chance of being salvaged altogether.

Comment: @TylerH It’s incredibly unproductive to start a discussion based on a ridiculous hyperbole. Your number is completely baseless. If you max out your close votes per day you would get at most a handful of notifications — maybe one or two per day, maybe more (and this may well turn out to be too much, but there’s no need to make up ridiculous numbers).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Where's the hyperbole? That's the number of close votes I've *actually cast*. Per day, I could get **40**, or even more if some questions are deleted allowing me to re-cast, notifications, not just "one or two" per day. If you want to be notified when a user edits an off-topic post in a pointless way, that's fine. But don't ask for everybody's time to be wasted along with yours.

Comment: @TylerH But only a tiny fraction of these are edited by the author (~17% *on a subset of close reasons* are edited, but the vast majority of these edits are *not by the author*), let alone in a substantial way (creating an automatic threshold may not be trivial but is entirely feasible). That’s the hyperbole.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's not hyperbole to say my experience is different from yours, it's just... reality. You for example have somehow never seen a question you voted to reopen get reopened. Chances of that happening over such a long period of time are way less than .01% I think. Either your sample size is way too small or your criteria for what qualifies for reopening needs some serious re-adjusting. Just glancing at my 1st page of reopen votes cast, only 4 out of 30 are still closed, and that's because 3 are deleted and the 4th was reopened, and then closed again by 3 other users.

Comment: @TylerH To be clear, me never having witnessed a reopening was since the recent introduction of the “follow” feature (and I don’t follow all questions I close, only those that I deem salvageable; I also haven’t used all my downvotes per day in quite a while). Your 0.01% number is once again purely made up, I bet the real number for this is way higher, *since this happened to me*.

Comment: roughly 57% of the reopen votes i have cast have resulted in posts being reopened. Maybe you're just trying to reopen posts that shouldn't be.

Comment: @KevinB Just want to chime in to say that it's also possible you've gotten fairly "lucky" with reopenings in the grand scheme of things too. You may very well be exactly right; your experience however, doesn't invalidate Konrad's. It sounds like the problem he describes isn't a niche, unshared one in the community, based on the responses to this post. Both experiences coexist, and neither appears to paint a good, full picture of reopenings.

Comment: @zcoop98 the majority of my reopenings were also probably dupe hammer reopenings after my own dupe hammer closures

Comment: @KevinB To clarify, the 0% I’m referring to do not include duplicates. Questions incorrectly closed as duplicates frequently get reopened.

Comment: Some numbers on these two answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355396/792066 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266844/792066. TL;dr: editing raises the possibility of being reopened the most. Of course popularity helps, but I say that's for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Here's an author whose question was closed, edited, and didn't get reopened. [He then reposted the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64694052/react-warning-appears-caliming-received-true-for-a-non-boolean-attribute-i), and was called out for doing so: *it was closed because i didn't add enough info, but did not reopen once I did, what was I suuposed to do?* I'm not saying he did the right thing, but neither do I know how to answer "What was I supposed to do?" It was discussed in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402673/should-this-question-have-been-reopened?cb=1).

Comment: @SuperJade It looks like the question was reposted very shortly after "fixing" it. So the thing they were supposed to do was to have patience.

Comment: SORVR Alpha testing: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227446/

Answer (score 57):

I for one would be interested to try getting a notification *after the first reopen vote* (from some other user) on a question where I am one of the close voters.

I expect that this won't be very cumbersome because the requirement of having a prior reopen vote would keep "false alerts" rate tolerably low - even in the unlucky case that most/all of these votes turn out worthless (thinking of such an unlucky case, we better have some way to opt out of these notifications).

Having participated in closing I am indeed in a fairly good position to reconsider and evaluate changes in the question because of prior knowledge.

However, we need to account for a possible risk that previous votes may lead to negative bias and favoring a Leave Closed outcome. It looks hard to tell how much of a risk this is and because of that I would suggest not to implement this immediately, but first run it as an experiment and decide after checking its results.

Said experiment would also help to find out whether close voters would feel comfortable enough about getting these additional notifications (we don't want prior voters stamping everything Leave Closed just because they are angry).

---

For the sake of completeness - [as was pointed in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402422/we-need-to-improve-the-chances-of-reopening-closed-questions/402437?noredirect=1#comment805469_402437), it probably would be logical to complement requirement that users whose vote triggers notification would also be other than asker. Personally I can't tell how much important this is because vast majority of my own close votes seem to be on questions from users having [less than 250 rep points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) who can't cast such votes anyway.

Comment: The close-voters are the best candidates to convince them join the other side, but this kind of notification could become annoying if question is still poor, especially if they have to spend time *again* to see it. So first reopen vote is a poor trigger. Trigger has to somehow *guarantee* what at least now it's worth to have a look.

Comment: I would not want to be included in this experiment by default.  Users should opt-in before getting notifications.

Comment: @Sinatr there can't be a guaranteed good trigger, and even if there was one, it would better go not to close voters but to moderators for binding reopen. I proposed prior reopen vote only as a means to limit amount of notifications, expecting the experiment to find out whether this trigger is good enough or too unreliable

Comment: @toolic I considered proposing explicit opt-in but after some thinking hesitated to add it because some may complain that this will make significant potentially interested audience unaware of the experiment. I am still chewing it, trying to figure a way to push it through with less friction, maybe have a banner or maybe something like first time opt-in ("click yes if you want to keep getting these notifications" at first time it pops up) or maybe something else

Comment: @toolic One could argue that you’re opting in by close-voting. — I also fail to see the issue of making an experiment opt-out rather than opt-in. It would be a one-time effort, whereas opt-in, as gnat says, would fail to reach those people it’s intended to reach.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if there was some magic metric that guaranteed a closed question was worth having a look at, we wouldn't need humans to evaluate Q's for reopening. It is possible, however, that some metric exists to help scrape off some of the posts that definitely don't add enough quality for reopening, even something like "OP added minimum *X* characters to post body", iff that was found to correlate.

Comment: @zcoop98 I've seen post closed that was edited into being fine **prior** to the last close vote being cast. So I do not think automatic character count or diffs is a good metric. I also do nothing to try to open them as I get the impression that users in the reopen queue are in fact presented with a diff. I assume when they see none, they're unlikely to vote to reopen.

Comment: This should have the additional requirement that the reopen vote also can't be by OP. With those two requirements: 'reopen vote cast by someone other than myself or OP' and this *might* work.

Comment: Perhaps after first reopen vote that is not by the author?

Comment: @TylerH I edited the answer to cover that

Comment: Some numbers on these two answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355396/792066 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266844/792066. TL;dr: editing raises the possibility of being reopened the most. Of course popularity helps, but I say that's for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 30):

In the end, the onus is on the asker for posting an on-topic question  before clicking the "post question" button, not on the rest of the community salvaging it afterwards. Forcing additional notifications on close-voters seems to me an impractical reversal of responsibilities.

To help those that initially fail on producing a good, on-topic question, but are amenable to feedback and end up salvaging it, I believe a couple of things could be done:

#### "Follow" notifications changes

I would fine-tune the behaviour of the recently implemented *"follow"* feature, to account for the following things:

- Notify when a question I'm following **is closed** (if I was interested on the question, I might be interested in it being closed, and might want to help with comments and reopen votes)
- Notify when closed question I'm following receives a reopen vote.

I think these two changes to an already existing, opt-in feature would be enough to help things flow more smoothly and may do something for the small amount of questions that are closed and are later salvaged but slip through the cracks. And more importantly, they would affect only users who actively want to use the feature **when** they want to use the feature. (I wouldn't mind these notifications on the questions I decide to follow, I think they would be useful).

#### Reopen queue changes

Another part of the "solution", such as it is, would to send less stuff to the reopen queue. The reopen queue is particularly unattractive, since most questions that get sent there by reason of an edit are still unfit for purpose (they haven't become on-topic, or they remain dupes).

Not sending closed questions to the reopen queue until they got a relatively substantial first party edit (or they received a reopen vote) would alleviate matters a bit, as suggested elsewhere. The remaining questions in the queue would have a greater chance to be seen, and the queue in general should, hopefully, become marginally more interesting.

Nevertheless, I think that it wouldn't have a revolutionary effect, since in my experience even first-party edits of closed questions are not generally enough to make a closable question worth reopening; the ones that do cross that threshold are a very small minority.

This change in behaviour for the reopen queue would be nice, but it has been mentioned already and does not appear to have made much traction with Stack Overflow.

---

Between those two changes I think it could be possible to have non-trivial impact on the reopen ratio of questions that deserve reopening. It's worth repeating that these questions represent a very small minority of the closed questions, but I appreciate the efforts of trying to "rescue" those that can be rescued, as they could become useful members of the community, and learn more in the process.

Comment: you had me at "the onus is on the asker... " :)

Comment: Maybe sending things to the reopen queue should be an explicit opt in that an editor can choose once. This would allow editors to defer sending to the reopen queue posts that they know are insufficient, whilst make it clear to the OP that they need to get everything sorted before sending to the queue.

Comment: @user1937198 Maybe. I think that's been mentioned elsewhere as well. I think that the effect that would have would be mostly accidental (by some users missing out in the hypothetical checkbox). I don't think that adding UI friction is way to go, but having smarter flows and triggers.

Comment: "the onus is on the asker... " - you are assuming that no questions are closed incorrectly

Comment: I'm thinking more on trying to make the fact that you get exactly one attempt to edit to trigger the reopen queue a bit more clear at the point of the edit might help.

Comment: @csgillespie No, I'm not assuming such thing at all. Rather, it's you the one making assumptions about my thought process. But I think that's not the problem this question tries to address, but that of the questions that are closed and later fixed. In any case, relaying on the close-voters for "questions closed incorrectly" seems rather inefficient, for that the second part of the answer, optimizing the way the reopen queue worked, would be a better fit.

Comment: There’s a lot of good stuff in this answer but I intensely dislike the first sentence. You (like many of us, occasionally me included!) seem to forget how hard it is to ask a good question. Let there be no doubt, **it’s really hard.** I know many very intelligent, highly educated people (we’re talking post-PhD level here) who have difficulty understanding what relevant context to include into a programming-related question, and which details are important vs. which ones aren’t. The questions we’re talking about here are by these people: well-intentioned, intelligent, diligent but inexperienced

Comment: @Konrad It's not about the posters being well-intentioned, intelligent, nice, diligent, polite friendly and frankly wonderful people all around that I like a lot and would love to help. It's about the questions. It's about the site. And I do remember how hard it is asking good questions, but those are the questions we want. I thought that the question was about reopening questions that weren't fit to begin with, but got salvaged. Nice! Totally on board with that! Now your comment seems to revolve about "we close too many questions", which I can't align myself with.

Comment: @yivi But you’re wrong, it *is* about the people asking questions. And, yes, how nice/polite/friendly they are is irrelevant, which is why I didn’t mention it. What matters is that asking good questions is a learned skill, and it’s on *us* to guide this process. Blocking people from learning the ropes is counter-productive and fundamentally misguided.

Comment: @yivi And my comment is explicitly about reopening questions, not about closing too many questions. And it is *in that context* that the first sentence of your answer is *deeply problematic*.

Comment: No @Konrad, you are wrong. The they are polite and nice and friendly is as irrelevant as all the rest. What matters are the posts. I'm all for reopening questions that became good, which was your original thrust. Now you are going all around about "blocking people from learning", which is unrelated. The vast majority of learning is performed by people reading existing posts, not by asking questions. Asking (good) questions just feeds more fuel into the machine so that future learners can benefit from.

Comment: I believe you either got sidetracked, or your original question does not reflect your motivation.

Comment: “The vast majority of learning is performed by people reading existing posts, not by asking questions.” — Passive learning is fundamentally limited. Almost nobody asks a good question the first time they try. This is simply a fact that we need to account for in our response to such questions (in general, but in particular in the context of facilitating reopening), and it is this fact which your opening sentence neglects. I’m not getting side-tracked, I’m focused on this one issue here.

Comment: I stand by my previous comment. This is going fundamentally nowhere. I believe my answer does address the fundamental issues of your posed question: alleviating the difficulty of reopening questions that deserve reopening. All the rest is just noise and unnecessary distraction. Please don't take it wrongly but I believe further discussion is sterile. Bye!

Comment: Another change that could be done to the reopen queue is that only when a question is edited by the OP it goes to the reopen queue. For the majority of questions, I don't believe that other person than the OP could turn a bad question into a good one. Also, it could be implemented a check box for edits to mark it as a minor edit, so it doesn't get bump into main page and to reopen queues.

Comment: @Magnetron I think that's already mentioned in my answer, isn't it? _"Not sending closed questions to the reopen queue until they got a relatively substantial first party edit [...]"_.

Comment: @yivi yeah, I missed the "first party" bit, sorry. About the check box for minor edits, it's a sugestion to how to implement what you mentioned in your answer (relatively substantial edit).

Comment: If it's really so rare for edits to make questions worthy of reopening, why do we consistently keep recommending that as the workflow?  Seems pointless to me.

Comment: @Mark Because without editing, is simply impossible. We recommend it for the cases where it’s actually can happen, and the whole premise of the question is about being more effective in those cases.

Comment: @MarkRansom Some numbers on these two answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355396/792066 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266844/792066. TL;dr: editing raises the possibility of being reopened the most. Of course popularity helps, but I say that's for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 27):

This discussion kind of makes apparent that there is still an illusion that someone who posts an initially poorly received question has a chance of making it out of the muck.

*Eons* ago, I had [proposed something similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259077/175248) since I saw what you're seeing - some questions may get dogpiled, but are still somewhat salvageable. But, five years later and I don't think anyone cares enough about this to do anything about it.

These days also, I'm a lot more cynical and jaded and I don't believe that it's worth the extra energy.  The problem that we have is that there is more of a flood of bad users and bad questions that come onto the site that takes away what precious volunteer time we have to spare.  We don't like rehashing the same old question that we saw and initially passed judgment on; it's inefficient.  Even my suggestion is inefficient for that reason since more volunteer time is used on questions which may not deserve it.

No one wants to say that you only really get one good chance at making a good and lasting impression.  We always look to the failsafes of review queues and editors acting in good faith to bail someone out of a jam.

The reality is that all of that is a lie, and there's a very real likelihood that one won't get out of the muck if they ask poor questions, or have their question closed.

Comment: I 100% agree with you regarding the large volume of bad questions. I do not suggest compromising on this. Unfortunately I also suspect you’re right with your two last paragraphs, but I’m simply not ready yet to concede the fight.

Comment: What doesn't seem part of the calculation is that bailing out users of jam seems like a possible way to get more future curators. The people who actually care about their own questions might also people who care about the site (if they weren't scared away).

Comment: @Trilarion Even if they aren't scared away by having their question closed, they'll be scared away by the review queues. It takes an extreme amount of mettle, and/or stubbornness, to be a Stack Overflow curator anno 2020.

Comment: As the old saying goes, you only get one chance to make a good first impression.

Comment: *"No one wants to say that you only really get one good chance at making a good and lasting impression."* Citation required. I say this regularly. It is probably one of my most-posted aphorisms on Meta. I find it especially compelling because it's true. The reopen system really is a fail-safe: it only handles cases where the review process truly *failed*. It isn't good at *recovery*.

Comment: @CodyGray: There's a silent, or omitted, or implied "that works here" that's missing from that declaration.

Comment: @CodyGray To counter with another aphorism, you seem to be conflating “is” with “ought”. Giving people only a single chance to get it right is a terrible state of affairs, and that should be self-evident. If that’s the current state of affairs it’s our responsibility as influential senior users to actively counter-act it, and to push for technological change to make this easier.

Answer (score 24):

This idea is cute at face value, but falls apart badly when you consider its Return On Investment.

I don't have a metric for the number of questions that get reopened after they are closed but I'm willing to put money on that ratio being *exceedingly poor*. (It would help your cause a lot if you could provide those numbers, BTW.) I generally use the entirety of my close votes every day, and of all of them, maybe (**maybe**) one is on a question that I think "might be answerable if edited" to myself as I cast my vote.

So anecdotally, 1 out of 50 questions, or 2%, would potentially be affected by this feature. Single-digit percentages are *not* what you target when you are looking to implement a new feature; you go for the best bang-for-buck. There are far more feature requests that will positively impact the userbase of this site in a far larger way than this suggestion, so its chances of ever being even *considered* for implementation are low.

Then you add on the fact that getting Stack Exchange to implement *any* feature, no matter how minor or valuable, is a Sisyphean task, and yeah... this one is DOA.

---

I will also echo part of yivi's excellent answer, regarding responsibility: to put it bluntly, if you don't want to have your question closed, *make it answerable from the start*. Because quite honestly, **it isn't difficult to write a good question**. Even with the lack of a centralised and simple FAQ on how to do so (something we can also thank SE Inc. for failing to implement), it really just boils down to these two pieces of guidance on the Ask page:

> Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person
> Include all the information someone would need to answer your question

99% of questions that get closed (or should be) fail one or both of those simple, fundamental requirements. That means the asker not only did not think about how to frame their problem to help it to be solvable, they did not even bother reading the Ask page. *Their* responsibility, which they abrogated.

At the end of the day, you don't go to an interview in your pajamas, get kicked out, then expect a do-over once you put on a suit. In the same way, you shouldn't post a bad question to Stack Overflow that gets closed, then edit it to be a (maybe) good question and hope it gets reopened and answered.

Don't waste everyone's time by doing the wrong thing first, then doing the correct thing: **do the correct thing to start with**!

Comment: “quite honestly, it isn't difficult to write a good question” — You‘re incredibly wrong here, and it’s frustrating to see this attitude in a high rep user. It appears, to put it bluntly, wilfully ignorant. It also means that we can’t debate this issue productively, because we’re starting off from incompatible positions. Luckily I believe the powers that be realise this, and won’t be swayed by your claim. So I’ll do my best to just ignore you.

Comment: There might be a catch 22 here. Maybe the feature is broken (at least that's what Konrad is saying). In that case, a low number of reopened questions would mean that it needs to be fixed urgently instead of concluding that it's not really important to change anything. And while I tend to agree with you, making mistakes is human. The way reopening works I guess the best thing would be to take a closed question, delete it, and start anew.

Comment: I think we can all agree that a *lot* of crap questions get posted, which get rightfully closed, and which will never be re-open worthy; that's clearly not in question here. I do nonetheless sympathize with the frustration that comes with not being able to reopen questions that *should* be reopened, which at the very least, seems more difficult than it was ever intended to be, based on the design of the tools that allow it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If you wish to make the claim that writing a good question is difficult, you need to provide evidence for it. (Please don't ask me to prove my claim to the contrary, because that would be asking to prove a negative.) Getting huffy and threatening to ignore me is an emotional response that benefits nobody. If you're truly interested in having your proposal *evaluated*, not just blindly accepted because you believe it's "right" from *your* moral viewpoint, then you need to leave your ego at the door.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Let me be clear: **I agree with the intent of this proposal**, as I do with the intent of pretty much *every* proposal that makes it to Meta.SO, because the people who are willing to post proposals here are almost always the kind of thoughtful, well-intentioned people who should really be in charge of running Stack Overflow. But... we aren't, and probably never will be, and that hurts. Hurts in a way that makes us jaded. Makes us seem dismissive of good ideas. Makes us seem hostile to new users. But we aren't bad people; we're just working in a bad system we can't fix.

Comment: I feel that @IanKemp. I really do.

Comment: Shog used to put out statistics, something like 4% of edited posts get reopened.

Answer (score 19):

The vast majority of closed questions should not be reopened, even if they've been edited.

1. OPs who post close-worthy questions are unlikely to have the skills or motivation to improve their question to the point where it can be reopened.
2. The question has already attracted close votes and sometimes delete votes.  All that damage is hard to undo, and requires several participants to undertake.  In most cases, if the OP can figure out how to ask a good question, it's better just to start over.
3. Nowadays I'm inclined to cast close votes only on those questions where I see that the situation is almost certainly not going to improve.  I've drastically curtailed my moderation activity, for the same reasons that Makoto articulates.

Comment: That's all okay but I wonder with only 3 close votes as threshold (and a question in the close vote review queue typically gets them) shouldn't there be lots of wrongly closed questions. It could be true at the same time that we close not enough questions and too many. Where would you say that the level of wrongly closed questions becomes a concern?

Comment: I would say wrongly closed questions becomes a concern when we're closing more questions per day than we're receiving. Otherwise... the damage is minimal. The question will be re-asked by someone eventually if it was one worth asking.

Comment: @KevinB I don't think that a fine Question is closed isn't a concern is true. The user that tried in good faith an failed may never ask again, especially if their Question was fine. They can't fix it, because it's not possible to make a fine Question fine. Someone else may ask it, but not as well, or it may be asked many times very poorly by users that know the game and just don't care. The bigger the flood, the more important it is to deal with the really poor Questions, because no one has time to fix the mistakes. Some users would make good curators, if they weren't dissuaded by injustice.

Comment: If the question truly was fine, asked well as it could be, and still closed, clearly it wasn't as truly fine as one thought.

Comment: @Scratte: "Dissuaded by justice?"  Apparently  you weren't here six months ago.

Comment: @KevinB That is a false assumption. Some of those posts are brought out on meta, and the issue is fixed for that one post. The problem is as always only a small amount is brought out on meta.

Comment: @Scratte Yes, because meta has absolutely no history whatsoever of proping up garbage questions

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was here, that's another "injustice". I am still here. I see posts closed that are fine. Not just to me, but to one or two other users mentioning it in comments expressing casting reopen votes. And then.. nothing. But what can I do about it? Other than not curate at all, hoping that the active close voters will focus on the crap instead?

Comment: @KevinB You can argue the same about all open Question. If it really is bad, then it would have closed already. Yet, some really bad ones don't get closed.

Comment: @Scratte You keep bringing up this crusade of yours on comments wherever you feel it's relevant even if it's really not, but on the rare occasion where you proffer an actual specific example, I feel it's actually not up to scratch.

Comment: Point 1 is just false and a bad bias to have. Point 2 is indeed a problem, but we shouldn't just resign ourselves to closing being final. Instead, we should do something about it... Point 3 is a poor choice IMHO; but - do you mean you downvote, or just comment on the question?

Comment: Point 1 is verifiable through data.  It would surprise me if more than 1 out of 10 questions got reopened through editing improvements.  Point 3 follows from point 1.

Answer (score 9):

Overall, as per [close stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats) for the last 30 days, 23.68% of questions asked get closed.

Most common reasons for closing:

- Needs details or clarity: 28.1%
- Duplicate: 22.4%
- Needs more focus: 15.8%
- Needs  debugging details: 12.6%

Of which,

- 6-20% of closed questions get edited
- 0-2% of closed questions get reopened
- 0-4% of closed questions which are edited get reopened

Overall, of all the close reasons, "Duplicate" questions get reopened relatively easy (2.3%). Of questions which are edited after being closed, "Needs debugging details questions" get reopened  relatively easy (4.03%).

---

We're dealing with two types of questions, that need to be reopened, in the reopen queue:

- Type I: Questions  which never  should have been closed: Wrongly closed questions: turbo/robo reviewers, looks based reviewers (no code = close + downvote).
- Type II: Questions which are salvaged by editing either by OP or others.

Most answers here simply deal with Type II questions, while Type I is completely ignored. We might lose future volunteers due to Type I.

---

It was mentioned that Return on Investment is low to consider this feature. *This new feature  only affects 2% of questions.* This is not true. Around 23% of questions asked are closed. Of these closed questions, in 6-20% of cases, either the OP or someone else cared enough to make an edit to put the question in the reopen queue. Not only that, some bad reputation of Stack Overflow due to downvotes/closed questions could be retracted, if we have a good reopen queue.

The most important positive outcome of fixing the reopen queue  is this:

- Close votes: Volunteers here care about the asker. They are not willing to vote to close, if they knew that their vote is irrevocable, even if OP does everything correct.  Users on Meta lament the poor questions and number of questions that are low quality that are not closed. But without a robust reopen queue, [borderline voters are not willing to cast a close vote, if they think the question is salvageable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402422/we-need-to-improve-the-chances-of-reopening-closed-questions/402458#402458). This creates a pool of low quality questions, which are  neither here nor there and is  always in a limbo (never closed, never salvaged, but not  clearly answerable either or attracts a poor answer). **To remedy the situation and increase close vote percentage, a robust reopen queue is  absolutely essential**.

Some other feature requests to consider:

- Trivial Edits: These type of edits: Tag edits, removing "Thank you"s and "Hi"s, code syntax highlights put the question in the reopen queue and unnecessarily flood the queue.

  - Automatically exclude these edits.
  - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Inform the OP/editor and/or ask their explicit permission to confirm whether they want this question to be put on the reopen queue after this edit.
- Better review audits: Since very low number of questions are eligible to be reopened, it is essential for the reviewer to have very high level of attention and not simply click "Leave closed". Custom audits specially designed for this purpose and/or increased number of review audits will help. A quota for the reopen queue will also help if this decreases reopen queue reviewers.

Comment: Thanks for this summary. It’s unfortunate that the statistics don’t tell us the extent of the editing — it’s entirely possible that the majority of the edits are minor or bad, and thus the questions really *don’t* warrant reopening (obviously I don’t believe this!). Even so, the reopen numbers are shockingly *even lower than I thought*.

Comment: Thanks for calling out the difference between the two types.  The first type seems like it should get a smoother pass to reopening.  A specific instance I have in mind are duplicate questions: a quick read making reviewers think it's a duplicate question, but a closer read shows that they're not really duplicates at all.  I've also had a question sit in limbo of the second type, where it was deemed too broad.  I narrowed the focus with an edit, but was unable to get it reopened despite that.  I wonder if there's therefore certain types of close reasons that should be more visible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think you can find the extent of edits using a SEDE query, but it still won't let you know the quality of those edits, which is much more important.

Comment: @M.Justin Duplicates *already* have a smoother pass, since they only require a *single* reopen vote from a gold tag badge user. In practice, this kind of reopening happens *frequently* (again, don’t have numbers but this is my experience and I’m sure SEDE would corroborate this). This is good, but it’s  not sufficient.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Although I agree Duplicate questions are reopened frequently. The opposite is also true, they only require 1 close vote from gold badge. This is especially important in tags where there aren't many gold badge holders. I agree with Justin on the fact that Some questions are closed as duplicates based on a cursory read of the question, which may not be true on a closer look.

Comment: The reopen stats are "the wrong stats": There should be some careful examination of some sample closed questions, by people congizant of this question - as an experiment, to determine what fraction of closed questions "should", given enough attention, be reopened. Then we should devide the actual fraction of reopened questions by this fraction.

Comment: "23.68% of questions asked get closed" That's an odd statement to say, so I went around checking what the screen says, and figured out what happened: questions closed on that percentage, has no relationship with questions asked other than both happened in the last 30 days. If a question asked in 2014 was closed in the last 30 days, it would be counted here. That 23% looks very impressive, but that's probably only because we are trying to clean the cruft of the non-compliant questions that weren't timely closed. BTW, if 90% of everything is crap, we need to pick up the slack.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've accidentally reopened questions that I didn't intend to, thinking others would need to agree with me first.  I can't even keep track of all the tags I have gold badges on now.

Comment: @Braiam I'm sure you'd agree that  such closed "old" questions  account for a minor part in that 23%- I would say, based on experience that they're almost negligible. Most of that closed questions are those that are asked in the last 30days.

Comment: One additional reason why so many questions are not edited after they are closed is because the closing process is so hostile. The close-votes are often accompanied by downvotes. When you're a new user and you post a question and immediately receive 3 downvotes and 3 closevotes, you're not encouraged to edit your question, you're encouraged to delete your question in shame. The feeling is similar to entering a room and asking a question, and the six people in the room jump at you and all simultaneously yell at you that everything you're asking is stupid.

Comment: @Stef I agree. Meta seems to hold inconsistent opinions on this: On one hand, they say Votes are only for [judging "content" and not the "user"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436), i.e., they're not "personal". I made a proposal then, to hide the votes from the "user", but [then they turn around and say votes are essential for the user to change the "content"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400284).  They maintain this hypocrisy to avoid any challenge to the status quo.

Comment: I fail to see how that's hypocrisy; are you saying that users who downvote should be taking the time to transcribe the code from an image? Do the research for the user? Show the user's attempts they failed to demonstrate? Why would the rest of the user base do that, @TheMaster . The *author* of the post is the only user who can improve a low quality post that is lacking detail and missing information. Any other user that did that would be hallucinating. The vote is for the content and if the user decides to improve their post because it received downvotes maybe those votes will be changed.

Comment: @ThomA When you say it is **for the content**, you also say it is **for future readers**. The [meta answer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437) that stated this entire rule says this clearly: *Downvotes are, first and foremost, a content rating system. Rather than being a way of communicating with the poster, they are a way of communicating to future readers that a question or answer is not interesting or useful. If someone wants to leave a comment to communicate with the poster, they can always do so, independent of the voting system.*  [1/2]

Comment: It clearly says it is communicating to future readers and adds that comments are for the poster. It also says votes are not exactly a way of "communicating with the poster". Do you at least see the inconsistency in claiming it's both for the op on one hand and not for the op,  on the other hand? [2/2]

Comment: So that future readers know the **content** is useful/helpful, @TheMaster . You added emphasis on the wrong place. That future reader may then also vote on that content. The cycle continues.

Comment: What do you mean by *"looks based reviewers"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I guess reviewing based on external appearances - presence or absence of code, markdown usage for beautiful appearance or bad appearance etc. rather than  actual meat of the question.

Answer (score 8):

Considering how many questions I've closed, I don't think I'd appreciate a notification every time they get edited (even if they are only when edited by the OP). Personally speaking, I can barely handle the notifications for following highly active questions. It'd be a nightmare if I got those types of notifications automatically.

That certainly isn't to say the Re-Open queue doesn't need help. It is getting backed up at the moment. It's just I don't think automatic notifications are the answer.

---

I propose an alternative. Why not model [what happened to the Close Vote Queue back in the day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251955/10957435) and start an organized effort to help make the queue more effective?

Obviously, [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) has since broadened its scope to moderation in general and not just closing. It could help tackle this problem (and might even be willing to help), but I personally don't think we as the community should try to put that responsibility on them and coax them to help. If we decide to go this route, it should ideally be a parallel effort in its own separate space.

To be clear: I am not suggesting creating an effort to re-open all the questions SOCVR closes. Instead, I'm suggesting we form an effort to find and re-open questions that **actually deserve** to get opened back up.

It is just a thought.

Comment: I'm not sure a 'dedicated' chatroom for reopen votes would really work (at least, not in the way that SOCVR impacted the size of the CV queue). Reopening is a fundamentally different beast than closing. Yes, the RO queue is rapidly gaining weight (something to do with ♦ Sam?) but, other than the changes 'in the pipeline' (non-OP edits not pushing closed Qs into that queue), I'm not sure how to coordinate folks' efforts into reducing that growth.

Comment: I generally do 40 RO reviews per day, [as do many others](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats). Many (if not *most*) I see are nowhere near worthy of reopening. I suppose what I (and others) could start doing is to post [reopen-pls] requests into SOCVR when one does pop up. Or just post the link to the review, to keep things 'clean'?

Comment: So SORVR?  Let's give it a try!

Comment: @TheMaster Well, if either you or Chipster get that going, I'd be happy to help out, if I can. But, as I said, I'm not sure what mechanism(s) to implement to actually pick up on the most reopen-worthy questions.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's not a bad idea; Obviously the request would have be subject to SOCVR's, though.

Comment: The ROs there may be able to add some kind of interface *directly* in the RO queue (may even be there - haven't noticed) to pump a [review-pls] request from the queue (like ♦Makyen's script does in the Suggested Edits queue).

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for the support. Obviously the same rules as SOCVR to begin with should work. A rationale provided by the reopen requester: if others agree, it'll be reopened, else left closed.

Comment: Btw, @TheMaster I'm certainly down for that, but I'd definitely like to wait and make sure it has sufficient community support before I try something like that. That being said, if you decide to go ahead and create such a room before I do, please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

I think two changes could greatly improve this situation:

- A question only goes to the re-open queue if it has a re-open vote on it.
- An asker can cast a re-open vote on their own questions at a very low rep (like 10 or so).

This way minor edits that don't intend to cause a re-open don't go to the queue.  And the asker can indicate when they are ready for the question to go to the re-open queue.  (Or a higher rep user can do an edit and cast a re-open vote.)

This would probably need some minor UI changes to make it easier for low rep users to find the reopen option after they have made their changes.

Comment: I think the reason why posts go into the reopen queue from an edit is that a lot of users do not know about the inner workings of votes, and what does what, and goes to which queues. I've encountered high reputation users making cosmetic edits to closed posts. They were unaware of the resulting push to the queue. I do not think one can expect a 1 reputation point or 10 reputation point user to know about the mechanics of the site.

Comment: Maybe it's time to learn them said inner workings @Scratte. The answer to people not knowing how the site works needs to stop being an excuse to repeatedly lowering our standards.

Comment: @KevinB Then information about those inner workings need to be easily accessible. Only [Fanatics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) (like me) spend months on meta to find out about everything. I wouldn't recommend it to someone else though.

Comment: It needs to be made clear whether the user can cast their reopen vote multiple times or not, and that they should only reopen if they've changed something. I imagine a lot of users, having had their question closed and seeing a freely available "reopen" link, will click it immediately without changing a thing, and continue to click it until the question is reopened or deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I feel that I VTC fairly often (maybe because of certain tags I subscribe to?) and always try to remember to *also* follow those questions, for the same reasons stated in the question here. Sometimes not, if it's in dire shape.

For me at least, I'd love an opt-out auto-follow feature. Either opt-out on the individual question (which pretty much already exists - you'd just unselect 'follow') or on a sitewide basis.

Since I already try to follow, and I find very few notifications result from this, I don't anticipate a "flood" of pointless notifications.

Comment: I also follow questions I VTCd unilaterally. But auto-follow would help a lot

Comment: UI/UX principles dictate features should be opt-in, not opt-out. Especially features that send you notifications. Or do you think people enjoy spammy/unsolicited emails, newsletters, and notifications? Voting does not constitute interest or involvement to a the degree necessary to merit automatic notifications.

Comment: @TylerH I was specifically talking about voting to close, not upvote/downvotes. I think the choice of opt in/out depends on what the intended expectation is when the person engages in a VTC. It is my *personal* preference that I am generally interested to continue engaging in the question. If SO preferred that close voters were to stay engaged, opt-out would be sensible. If not, opt-in would be. I don't think that general UI principles overrule that intention.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs So was I. "Voting" encompasses all forms of voting, including close and reopen voting.

Comment: @TylerH where was the term "voting" used that you are referring to? In any case I was not suggesting opt-out for anything but VTC.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Your post says you want an opt-out auto-follow feature after talking about your efforts to follow questions you *vote* to close. Voting to close is something I do *quite* often and also is quite often done on posts where no amount of editing would salvage them/make me interested in re-visiting (e.g. recommendation questions, topics far too broad for SO, things not remotely about programming). Especially for people who are active in the queue vs people who only close vote organically, this would be way, way, way more noise than signal.

Comment: @TylerH thanks, I understand what you meant now.

Answer (score -4):

I think I have seen statistics which are ballpark 4% of closed questions *with edits* get re-opened.

In order to address this from a community angle, it could be possible to identify which close reason (if any) are primarily the cause of closed questions which could have remained open and then have a moderator modify that close reason to be a little more vague in order to prevent the question from being closed if it is close enough to salvageable that you could envision an edit saving it.

However, that is assuming that questions which are salvageable actually have an associated asker attentive enough to fix them. I think that making sure the asker is more attentive through some sort of grace period of closing would be a good approach here, and would also keep the onus on the asker as opposed to the community.

**I propose a similar time window to that of the accept answer time window (10 minutes) whereby no close votes can be cast (unless the question reaches -5 votes).**

You may be thinking, "What? Why?! What does that accomplish? Now I can't close vote clearly garbage questions and in addition users will just downvote faster in order to be able to vote to close." which is a fine instant reaction. The thing is, a 10 minute window allows the OP to have a sense of urgency to edit when they first post. Clearly just suggesting that they be attentive is not enough, there must be some sort of associated measurable metric. I think this accomplishes that, and should encourage edits. It would be easy to A/B test, where edits in the first 10 minutes would be the measurement to make, and there could be a timer shown somewhere in the UI to indicate that the grace period was ending in x minutes and y seconds. This also encourages downvotes! So, to everyone always clamoring that there isn't enough downvoting on questions: you're welcome. Historically we have discussed the use of close votes for certain types of questions, and their failures; many times in those conversations the use of downvotes had emerged, so this really does pair hand in hand with that. Using a 5 downvote threshold for close votes comes from those discussions. While this may seem like a lot of stick, there is an equal amount of carrot. In addition to the theoretical situation posed here, from the technical end, the hook already exists for accepting an answer, so that would be easy to piggy back into.

Comment: That seems sort of counter to the proposal to get Questions reopened. What is the point of having one or two highly downvoted open posts, even if one learns to post Questions, if the result is a Question ban? Wouldn't it effective make the users that have learned it explicitly barred from using their new skills?

Comment: @Scratte - This is a situation best approached prior to the closing, rather than after. Also, downvotes can be reversed. For posts which can be edited to be good questions, most users who downvote will reverse that vote, and will feel inclined to stay if there are edits being made. If a post is being edited, it is less common for it to receive downvotes or close votes. Once a post is abandoned, then it really doesn't stand a chance to be reopened, as the asker has either given up, or the question itself was not in a place to be remedied.

Comment: That is the sort of hidden statistic here, that most questions closed stand no chance at being reopened; moreover, that many askers simply abandon posts once asked. These are two important facets that this approach would address with regards to reopening, because, let's be honest: **the issue isn't reopening, it's editing**.

Comment: A close-worthy question should not, IMHO, be downvoted - just closed.

Comment: Depends on the question; is it well researched, does it present as an actual question, is it related to programming in the proper aspects, etc.. Many close worthy questions merit downvoting, and many questions not qualifying for a close reason merit downvoting as well. It is certainly true that qualifying for closure is not an immediate reason to downvote.

Answer (score -5):

#### Re-opening alone isn't good enough.

Questions have a brief window to show in the Top Questions view. My impression with the re-opened questions I've been able to encounter is the recovered question already seems stale. They still don't get attention in the same way as a regular new question, and will still tend to go unanswered.

I will say that I really like the proposal. I just think we need to do that **and** something else.

Most of all, I like that **this proposal is likely to act as a modest deterrent to close votes**, because any close vote is now likely to also come with a later nag notification to review. And I think that's a good thing:

> Two simple @StackOverflow
> tips when looking at questions from new users:
>
> 1. If you're about to cast a down-vote, a close vote is almost always the better choice.
> 2. If you're about to vote to close, at least half the time an edit is the better choice
>
> https://twitter.com/jcoehoorn/status/1166576471843975169

Comment: Your advice confuses the role that each vote plays.  A downvote is meant to judge the question *quality*.  A close vote judges the question's *topicality*.  An off-topic question could also be poor, but a poor question is not necessarily off-topic.

Comment: @Makoto I think *Joel* isn’t confusing them, he’s saying that many *voters* confuse them. And it’s not always that clean cut. “Needs focus” and “Needs details” can both be on focus and just low quality, and both are good candidates for reopening after the question has been cleaned up in some cases.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  I'm sure that the quoted tweet there *definitely* confuses those things.  Downvoting and close voting are not mutually exclusive and send different messages in different ways.  Close voting implies the question is not on topic **in some way**, be that focus, broadness, duplicate, or whatever.  Downvoting implies that the question is poor **in some way**.  The advice that a close vote should be used when the question is still on-topic but not that great is horrible advice, and the idea that editing a post that needs to be closed instead is also horrible.

Comment: @Makoto I don’t disagree with your characterisation of voting. I still think you are misunderstanding the tweet, because it doesn’t disagree either.

Comment: No, I think [I do understand those roles.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LE0ORmUSqiM&t=13). I think most others do, too. But those features were built to include wide berths for discretion. Over the years that discretion has tilted far too much towards closing+downvoting weak questions, especially for new users, when edits or comments might be more fruitful -- often to the detriment of the site as a whole. I also believe very strongly in question quality standards, but I think the way to get there is teaching those who come here to do better, not shutting them out or driving them off.