# Closed question improved – what next?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

A couple of days ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513451/continuously-develop-and-deploy-a-django-app-with-visual-studio-code-and-docker) and it got immediately closed with the following feedback:

> Closed. This question does not meet [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is
> not currently accepting answers.
>
> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools,
> software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered
> with facts and citations. You can edit the question or [post a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

I did not know that about recommendations (and it's not mentioned in the linked guidelines, by the way). I googled for "stackoverflow reopen" and the first hit was "[What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)".

I **removed the concerned paragraph** and made a note to this change. As mentioned as "Additionally, you can … number 3" I flagged it for moderator attention. That was declined with the hint, that anyone else but a moderator could do that.

OK, I added a comment to my question (according to recommendation number 1) and since then I have been waiting. I have to admit, my question is not ideal and quite general, but at least the obvious flaw given as the closing-reason has been removed.

**Is there anything else I could do now to accelerate the process of reopening my question?**

Besides that, the whole process of reopening a question is not very clear for someone relatively new to StackOverflow like me and I wonder if

- there should be a link from the close message to the help document and
- the help documentation itself could be somehow more clear?

This would be a minor improvement, I also found a [proposal for a more profound change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402422/we-need-to-improve-the-chances-of-reopening-closed-questions).

Comment: Is [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) not clear enough about recommendation questions being off-topic?

Comment: Sure, you are right. How could I miss that? Anyway, after removing that paragraph everything should be OK, right?

Comment: Asking multiple questions is a reason for closure as is asking for opinions such as "is this a good way"

Comment: I see, so the given reason was not the only one which led to closure. It would be easier to follow if all reasons were given, of course.

Comment: Those reasons are in the article that Jeanne Dark linked and also in the closure link about not meeting Stack Overflow guidelines - the one you referenced in this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sorry but that question is not even close to be in a state where it's a good candidate for reopening.

After a very long introduction (which does nothing for your question but make it harder to parse, I understand you think making it conversational is "friendly", but it really does not help to make the question easier to understand, and it's seen as "noise" on the site), we get to the actual questions:

> Before I invest further efforts into this I just wanted to make sure if I am still on the right track. Is the way I have in mind a good one to continuously develop and deploy a Django App, I mean testing and debugging locally with Visual Studio Code and Docker as described and then deploying that to wherever?

This is mainly a yes/no **opinion based** question. One could generously attempt to understand it as "how to develop a Django application", and would simply be **too broad** for the site.

> I do not totally understand yet how much effort I will have to put later into running the app in regards of updates, security and so on. I assume Google Cloud Run for instance cares about everything but my Docker container (including my own code). So it's me who has to make sure that I am using the right version of Python, Django and every other package and that my code itself is secure, of course, but Google does the rest – am I right with that?

This one is a second, separate question from the first (which would alone make the question closable as "needing focus"), but the second question itself is also too broad. It's asking another primer in application development, hosting and maintenance.

This kind of topic is better served by the many blogs and tutorials you'll find online. Once you covered the basics, you can come back to the site with **practical and focused** questions, which you should ask **one at a time**, and trying to stick to the matter at hand, telling **all that's necessary** to understand and answer the question, but telling **only what's necessary** as well.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks you a lot! So until I come back with more specific questions (if still necessary) I should delete now my original question, right?

Comment: @RalfZosel you won't be able to, it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @RalfZosel Warming: Deleted questions still count toward a potential question ban. When possible, it is better to fix a question than hide it from sight.

Comment: @RalfZosel - You should never seek to destroy a question and unless you are unable to clarify it and get it to be reopened.  Every question you submit, counts towards or against, your ability to ask questions.  If you ask a lot of questions, only for them to be deleted, you will quickly find your unable to ask new questions.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks a lot for this hint. I reformulated my question taking into account what I have learned here. I hope now it is OK. I voted to undelete it (and still need some votes).

Comment: Despite the above advice, undeleting that question won’t really help you. And the new version is as off-topic as the previous one.

Comment: yivi is right. Not everything can be fixed. Sometimes you have to cut your losses and protect the question from further downvotes by removing it. But if you can fix it, do fix it.