# Some questions are closed for not being clear or minimal when the issue is clear to some readers

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Based on the feedback from the comments and my editing of this question, my actual feature-request is a duplicate of:

[We need to improve the chances of reopening closed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402422/we-need-to-improve-the-chances-of-reopening-closed-questions)

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

---

Recently I've seen a few questions closed for `not being clear or include a minimal example`, but where the question as is contains enough information for some readers to post a proper answer, based on those readers familiarity with what the question is asking about, such as some known caveat(s) or common mistakes made when implementing a particular algorithm.

I've seen a few cases where someone commented that they had prepared an answer, but found the question was closed by the time they were ready to post their answer. Generally they will summarize what would have been in their answer.

Based on some comments here, if the community feels the need to close questions ASAP, then there should be a better way to communicate to the closers that the question has been edited. Apparently, unless a closer chooses to follow the question, they don't get notified of an edit update.

Comment: These determinations will always be subjective to some degree. It can't be helped. If you are in this predicament where you find such a closed question, consider editing it to help improve its clarity (if your sure that you understand the author's intent) and improve its utility for future visitors, and then possibly route it to the re-open queue.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Unfortunately, there is little point to editing a closed question.  They almost never get reopened as those who vote to close are not notified of edits.  I advise the OP to take the improvements they've learned to make their question clear to everyone and post a new question.

Comment: @jfriend00: that is not necessarily true. If you are the first to edit the question *and send it to the re-open queue* (by clicking the appropriate checkbox), it *will* go to the re-open queue for review. The danger of asking a new question rather than improving the old, is that the old one will probably be deleted and will count against the OP if they are at risk of a question-ban.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - What is the reopen queue?  I've never seen a question come back to life that way.  It appears to me to need some number of reopen votes to ever get a chance at getting reopened and it just doesn't happen very often - as best I can tell that process just doesn't succeed much.  Yes, the OP needs to worry about a question-ban if they post another bad question (so they need to make sure they've fixed the question).  But spending energy on a closed question is very unlikely to be fruitful.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain why clarifying such question with edits is not an option and why one who has the answer ready is not willing to post the question themselves with self-answer. Also make sure to address concerns from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing.

Comment: Yes, it is disappointing to be working on an answer to a question you think you understood, only to hit the "Post Your Answer" button and find that others have closed the question.  That has happened to me dozens of times here.  Other than convincing people to not be quite so quick to issue the close vote, I don't know what else to do.  There's a culture here to immediately get rid of imperfect questions and leave the OP to deal with the consequences rather than engage and see if the question can be clarified.

Comment: @jfriend00 For the last few years, close voters have had the option of following the question. However, I only follow questions I close-vote if I think there's a reasonable chance that the question will be salvaged. That partly depends on the state of the question, and partly on how responsive the OP is to comments.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you edit an unclear question you need to be fairly confident that your edit is actually clarifying the OP's intentions, and that you aren't altering their question to conform to the answer you want to write.

Comment: @PM2Ring - Yeah, but drive-by close voters who leave no comments are not very likely to do that.  If the default changed so that you automatically followed any question that you voted to close, then you would get notified when it gets edited.  But without that being the default, it's mostly a feature that doesn't get used and doesn't solve the issue here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Fair point. I agree that it's probably a good idea to make it the default (but I'm sure plenty would hate it). And there's probably a ton of old-timers who forget that following is possible, and I guess newer members who don't know it exists, too.

Comment: @PM2Ring - Yeah, I'm been around here awhile (10 yrs) and spend a lot of time here (13k answers) and I only even knew what "following" was about a month ago.  I imagine I'm not alone.  It seems to me that if you're going to vote to close, then you SHOULD auto-follow.  Knowing when the question has been edited and possibly fixed should be part of what you accept when you vote to close.  That's an interesting idea.  If there are fewer drive-by close votes because they don't want to bother with being notified of an edit or don't want to both unfollowing, then that's no great loss in my book.

Comment: @rcgldr Questions need to be clear to the majority of readers who have some knowledge of the problem domain, not just the experts. That is, it needs to be clear to future readers who may have the same (or similar) problem, not just the potential answerers. If you're confident that you understand the question, that's great. But I'd generally try to use comments to guide the OP into clarifying it, rather than editing it myself.

Comment: OTOH, if the question just needs some improvements to grammar, and the OP obviously doesn't have great English skills, then sure, I'll just edit it myself.

Comment: @rcgldr In that case, you should still try to get confirmation from the OP that you've interpreted the question correctly *before* you post your answer. The whole point of closing unclear questions ASAP is to prevent answers from people who are just guessing at what the OP means. If multiple answers are posted by people who all guess differently, you get a chaotic mess that can confuse the OP and future readers.

Comment: I'm not claiming that the current system is perfect, far from it. And I admit that the odds of a closed question getting improved & reopened are not good. I wish more people would post constructive comments, rather than simply down or close voting. But I also wish more OPs would respond constructively to those comments. I've seen tons of posts across the network where the OP makes some totally inadequate edit to their closed question, and then  is puzzled why we don't reopen it.

Comment: *"But I also wish more OPs would respond constructively to those comments."* - And that is the root of the problem.  After a few thousand non-responses or inadequate responses, we just lose patience.  Do you have a good way to recruit lots more experienced people willing to play the "post constructive comments" lottery on StackOverflow?

Comment: No that is not a proper minimal representative example.  A proper minrep includes the expected and actual results.

Comment: That's beside the point.  A minimal representative example should include the expected and actual results.  It should not be necessary to run to code to find out what the error message is.

Comment: @PM2Ring - continuing - in the case where comments stated the OP needs to show more effort, I can understand that, but the question should not be closed, since that seems to discourage OP's from editing their question, if they feel there's no chance of getting the question re-opened.

Comment: The [minrep canonical link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) says this: *"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.".*

Comment: I agree with StephenC. The OP has just dumped their code without the slightest mention of what their actual problem is, or what error messages they're getting. At least it's a complete runnable example, and kinda sorta minimal.

Comment: FWIW, here's a nice quicksort question I answered years ago. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33752201/4014959 The OP made some attempt to explain their problem, and responded with an appropriate edit when I pointed out that their code was incomplete.

Comment: @rcgldr I won't close-vote https://stackoverflow.com/q/71629904 but it *really* needs to be edited. But if we edit it, we'll just be putting words into the OP's mouth, which directly goes against the "don't make edits which conflict with the author's intent" policy.

Comment: @PM2Ring - this is getting off topic about one specific question. Getting back on point is the issue of questions getting closed that could be answered properly, even if only by some and not the majority of readers, in such a manner that it would benefit a majority of readers. This is an opinion that jfriend00 and I seem to share.

Comment: It's ok to post hints or helpful links in comments. But posting links to full answers to closed questions is frowned on, and such comments risk getting deleted.

Comment: The point is not that whether or not the question *could* be answered.  It is whether it should be left open once it was answered.  Especially since (in the case you identified) the OP has shown zero interest in fixing the question.  My feeling is that a question that meets the criteria for closure should be closed.  If people want to answer it anyway in an answer or in comments that is fine.

Comment: But until and unless the question poster is prepared to fix the question to address the closure reasons, it should not be left open ... gathering random hits, confusing / wasting the time of other readers who are using the Stack Overflow site as information center (as it is intended to be) rather than a help desk (which it isn't).   (Despite having a votes -4,  that Question has still managed to get a 100+ visits so far.  While a lot of those visits will be due to this Meta question ... it won't be all of them.  It is hard for us to know.)

Comment: @StephenC - I updated my question, to basically state that perhaps the default action for closing a question would be to get a notification that the question has been edited.

Comment: *there should be a better way to communicate to the closers* - the closer-person list is shown to the OP in the banner? "Closed just now by ..., ..., ... because..". They could @... those people if they felt the need; if I'd closed a question and was subsequently @'d I'd review it - I think it only fair, having taken (part in) action to close it, that I be instrumental in reopening if my concerns were resolved

Comment: @CaiusJard - This is covered in the question that mine is a [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402422) of.

Comment: The only true solution is to make it so questions do not need to be closed to begin with, because they were not allowed to enter the system (visibly) in a poor state. That is the only way to deal with a site that has the scope of Stack Overflow - prevent rather than correct. That being said, I would not be apposed to a tab in my user CP which holds the latest questions I close voted on which shows they were edited since I cast that vote. Then I can choose for myself to act without getting an avalanche of notifications from the system.

Comment: @Gimby -  one issue is what the duplicate thread comments calls type 1: questions that probably shouldn't have been closed in the first place. I've seen a few cases where minimal (full program code) examples were included, clearly stated what the failures were (for example, data not being sorted properly), and clearly stated what the expected results should have been (for example, data being sorted properly). The questions that were closed by some while others were going to answer, only to find the questions closed would be a grey area, a difference of opinions.

Comment: I don't usually pipe in on these things, but seeing as how I was the one who reverted the changes to the question, and voted to close it again, I figure I should. I tend to agree with what Stephen C is saying. Basically, while you might be right with what you think OP was actually asking in that question, it's impossible to know for sure, because only OP can clarify what their actual issue was. I think the more likely problem was that they were trying to use too much stack space, however, that is only a guess, and hence not an answer, which is why I voted to close as needing details.

Comment: I reverted the changes to the question you'd made because it seemed more like guess work. I looked through the comments to see if OP had said anything, which the edits would have been made based off of, but I did not see anything (of course, it's possible those comments were deleted, I really don't know). Thus, the edits seemed like guess work, and changed the meaning of the question, imo.

Comment: @ChrisMM - I"m not sure why you're posting about this here, but the OP had commented about stack overflow and although that comment was deleted, there was a reply to that comment. The OP should have updated his question to match his one or two comments that he deleted. I did not have an issue with you reverting the edit I made to the question, since the comments that edits was based on were deleted.

Comment: @rcgldr, just adding the comments here because the comments here referred to that question. Your question here is about why questions are closed, and that would be the reason why that specific question was closed. Of course, it doesn't apply to all questions.

Comment: @ChrisMM - My question is a duplicate of a prior question, and covers the situation I wrote about in my question, so there's no need for my question above any more other than to note it's a duplicate. In the prior thread, the issue in my question was described in the prior question's comments as "type 1 - questions that should never have been closed in the first place".  I didn't mean to focus on just that one example, which was a grey area one, since it was closed, reopened, and then closed, so clearly a difference of opinions on that one.

Answer (score 8):

First and foremost the question has to be written in such a way that it is helpful to the future readers. Is the issue properly described? Will other people search for the same problem hoping to find the potential answer to this question? Do we have all the details needed to exclude unrelated issues, e.g. XY problem? If the answer is yes, then the question should probably be left open and answered.

Bear in mind that even if a question can be answered, it doesn't mean that it should be answered. Sometimes the root cause is a simple typo, misunderstanding of the problem or a question in style "can somebody help me". A skilled developer might figure out what the OP is asking for, but does answering such a question actually help the community? I think not.

We want to close questions ASAP to prevent low-quality answers. They usually come from new Stack Overflow users who are not yet experienced enough to understand what is a useful question and what isn't. Of course, it doesn't mean that we want to close all questions. Just the ones that are truly not clear enough to be usefully answered. If the question asker edits the question and improves it, then feel free to cast your reopen vote. There's no need to notify the original close voters, because the question can be placed in the reopen review queue where **other** people will give their opinion on how clear it is.

Comment: My question is a duplicate of a prior question, and covers the situation I wrote about in my question, so there's no need for my question above any more other than to note it's a duplicate. In the prior thread, the issue in my question was described in the prior question's comments as "type 1 - questions that should never have been closed in the first place".