# How long does it take for the review process to be completed?

Tags: support, review-queues, closed-questions, reopen-review

I asked a question recently that was closed with

> Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

This was done and it was submitted for review 8 days ago.

How long does it take for the review process to be completed?

Comment: There is no set time and no guarantee that the review will be favorable. It is unfortunate, but how the site works.

Comment: But also note that the site was never built to be a personal help site but rather a question and answer site, meaning it is incumbent on the asker of the question to ask as interesting and high-quality question as possible, one that is well-researched and presented, as this can increase the likelihood of getting a decent response and an answer. It is not easy to ask a well-received question on the site, and has gotten more difficult over time, since more questions asked now are essentially duplicates of ones that have been well-asked and answered previously.

Comment: The company behind stackoverflow spend years alienating the users who did most of the curation work, like reviewing reopen requests.

Comment: Also, if [this is the question of reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77717759/), I see that you've posted code, but not a valid [mre] as yet.

Comment: what does [mre]  mean ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, on the [main] main site, [mre] expands to [this MRE link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the one that was given to you on question closure. I'm not 100% clear on your question either. It's likely me, since I'm no pro in that field, but consider clarifying your question as much as possible as well.

Comment: The code i have added is an exact except from the website so should surely count as MRE  ?

Comment: @Stevo: remember that you are asking volunteers to do work, and so it is always in your best interest to make it as easy for them to do so. The MRE is valid if it can be copied and pasted in full and then run and demonstrate the problem. So, for your problem, a small complete HTML page that someone can copy-paste-run and that demonstrates the issue would be best. The MRE should have enough code so that it runs and demo's the problem, but avoid any other unnecessary code.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not possible for me to do.

Comment: Why not? You should be able to do it with [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @Stevo - If you can’t provide a MRE then our ability to help you will be limited.

Comment: If I understood HTML I wouldn't be here asking questions about it.  The code I posted gives the structure of the HTML which has been proved in other questions in the past and used to give an answer  without the need to run as an MRE for the solution to be given.

Comment: All of this seems a little irrelevant.  As there seems to be no review process.

Comment: *"As there seems to be no review process."* There *is* and, for those have have to it, it's found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen). That your question may take some time to be reviewed is what your *real* concern should be. At the moment there are almost 400 reviews outstanding, and each review will 3 users to vote to reopen for a question to be opened. That can, and will, take time, and it's why it's so important that you put the time and effort into the *initial* revision of your question.

Comment: @Stevo I am addressing your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427757/closed-edited-and-submitted-for-review#comment983903_427757), which I quoted: *"As there seems to be no review process."* I am sorry if you feel I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @ThomA "*At the moment there are almost 400 reviews outstanding,*" for even more context, that's *only* in the reopen queue. There are eight queues. And the reopen queue is the third *smallest* one..

Comment: Please research before considering posting or commenting a question.

Comment: "I copied the rendered address text (label text) from the page and used it to click on the 'fulladdress' attribute using" - I can't make any sense out of this: the code doesn't say `fulladdress` in it anywhere; and "attributes" aren't things that you click on in a UI, but instead the components of objects in a running program.

Comment: "But the 'fulladdress' no longer matched the label text." - This doesn't concretely describe the problem. When you try using the code, how exactly do you know that there is a problem? For example, if the problem is "some variable in the JavaScript gets the wrong value", then we should see enough code to where you can point at the variable in question, say what value it gets, and say what value you think it should get instead (and why).

Comment: Please re-read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and do your best to make sure that someone else can run the Stack Snippet **without adding or changing anything** and see the **exact problem, directly**, and state what that problem is, clearly enough that anyone could verify that the problem is occurring. Right now, all the snippet does is lay out the HTML elements you mentioned in describing the problem; it doesn't try any interaction nor explain what is supposed to happen as a result.

Comment: To be frank, it's not even clear to me why you expect that clicking on a label (whether by code or manually) should "select" it, nor what you expect it to mean that the label is "selected". If the question is specifically about making the document selector select the right tag, then you should a) **say that**; b) focus the example on the actual selection, rather than the semantics of clicking on whatever was selected; c) show code that **clearly demonstrates** what was selected and what should be selected instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [We need to improve the chances of reopening closed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402422/we-need-to-improve-the-chances-of-reopening-closed-questions)

Answer (score 15):

It takes as long as it takes for those volunteer reviewers to go through the queue to get to your review.

For instance you asked your question on December 26th and it was closed that same day as you provided all the HTML markup as an image rather than as text.

You edited the question later that day. At that point you clicked on the checkbox to confirm that you'd fixed the issues that caused the question to be closed in the first place. Your question completed the review process on December 28th. It was left closed in review because you still hadn't converted the markup from an image to text.

So in the first instance your question was reviewed in 2 days.

You then deleted the question and undeleted it on January 6th when you edited it again, this time finally converting the image to text. That second review of your question is still in progress.

So far 6 volunteers have reviewed your question and we'll need another 3 to review it again.

Comment: so you are not able to give a definitive answer as to How long does it take for the review process to be completed ......  so you dont have a correct answer

Comment: @Stevo This answer is correct: the time taken for the review process to be completed is mostly unpredictable. Describing this and the surrounding circumstances is a valid and useful answer in this context.